# Retrieve image from database using CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

this code work only in admin page but can't work in view page how to retrieve image from view page in codelgniter

code:

```
<?php
include('config.php');
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM photos");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo '<div id="imagelist">';
    echo '<p><img src="'.$row['location'].'"></p>';
    echo '<p id="caption">'.$row['caption'].' </p>';
    echo '</div>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why you use `mysql extension` in codeigniter ?!

Even though the meaning of that code work in admin is you store your image inside admin folder

So for best practice

Please use codeIgniter as a FrameWork not a place to paste your procedural PHP code !
Also show us what is in `$row['location']` ?!